# How app detect that xposed framework is installed?

Tags: android, xposed

some apps like Summoners War will not start if xposed framework is installed. What I want to know is how this game detect xposed framework.Because I searched through the game files and there was no mention for the word xposed.It seems like it detect it in memory.

Answer (score 1):

First, that you don't find the word `xposed` somewhere in the code doesn't say anything. Even a simple string obfuscation like [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) will be sufficient to hide it from your eyes.

Xposed itself can be detected using several ways: Using the files it installs or modifies and second more important using the stack-trace within your app. If Xposed is installed this is visible in the stack trace as Xposed is loaded into the Dalvik VM and therefore is active in each and every app.

BTW: Have you tested the Root Cloak module? For a lot of apps it can hide the root and Xposed status.